# How to print Google Drive File Names from URL in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Frankenstein-ed a few codes from around here, but have been unable to fiddle with code values to correctly call my data. Forgive me, it's been years since I last coded seriously.

Here is the code I've been using. I want to grab links (to Google Drive PDFs) from Column B (B2:B) and have them print in Column D. I keep getting an error message that

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 10).

```
function getIdFromUrl(url) { 
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); 
}

function getFileNames() {
  var driveApp = DriveApp;
  // SET THE SHEET HERE
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Archive Log");
  //SET THE URL LINK COLUMN HERE : From row 2 since row 1 is the header row till last row
  var links = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();

  var filenames = []; 

  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var fileId = getIdFromUrl(links[i][0]);
    if (fileId != "" && fileId != null) {
      var getfile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
      var filename = getfile.getName();
      Logger.log(filename);
      filenames.push([filename]);
    } else {
      filenames.push([""]); 
    }
  }

  // SET STARTING ROW TO PRINT: From row 2 since row 1 is the header row
  var startRow = 2;
  // SET WHICH COLUMN TO PRINT : Column A = column 1 / Column B = column 2
  // MAKE SURE THE SHEET LAST COLUMN HEADER IS FILLED + 1 (next column)
  var fileNameColumn = 4;  
  var destination = sheet.getRange(startRow, fileNameColumn, filenames.length, filenames[0].length);
  destination.setValues(filenames);
}
```

Comment: Please be ware that if your project is a stand alone app script file. when you trying to access Spreadsheet, you have to call SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Archive Log")` returned null. This happens when the spreadsheet hasn't a sheet with the name passed to `getSheetByName`.

The way to fix this is by providing the name of an existing sheet. Please bear in mind that the sheet name is case sensitive.